# In zsh, how can I dump all configuration?

Tags: zsh

How can I print my current configuration including defaults and key bindings?

This would allow me for example, to find what action is bound to say `^P` in emacs mode and find binding in `vi` mode or set if it is not there instead of browsing manuals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All key bindings:

```
for m ($keymaps) bindkey -LM $m
```

All ZLE user widgets

```
zle -lL
```

All zstyles:

```
zstyle -L
```

Loaded modules:

```
zmodload -L
```

All variables:

```
typeset -p +H -m '*'
```

With the `zsh/parameters` module loaded, that will also include aliases, options, functions...

Comment: Great answer. But be careful with `typeset -p +H -m '*'`, the output may break your terminal, if not redirected, as there are a few variables containing escape sequences, for example `terminfo`.